# Make hard links as I copy a directory

Tags: windows-7, hardlink

I would like to create a bat file to copy a directory, with everything in it (sub-directories, including hidden directories) - by making hard links.

I tested `xcopy %source% %destination% /E /C /R /I /K /Y`

I haven't seen anywhere an option to make hard links though...

Is there any way to copy and make hard links at the same time ?

Comment: What is the advantage of hard-links for each file instead of one soft-link for the whole directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own script in c++, with the advantage (over kinokijuf's solution) of less overhead, plus I can choose which files to copy and which to hard-link.

Comment: You should paste the source code here if possible, so that others can benefit from it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html). It has an option to create a „Hardlink Clone”.